# My uinavigationbar doesn't display the name of the right uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am popping to the desired viewcontroller, but the uinavigationbar and uinavigationitem don't display the right name and I have to click on the back button(uinavigationitem) in order to see the right name on the navigationbar.

I am using

```
     YTOCalculatorViewController * parent = (YTOCalculatorViewController *)self.controller;
     [self.navigationController popToViewController:parent animated:YES];
```

in order to display YTOCalculatorViewController. I have placed this code in viewwilldisappear of the viewcontroller from where I want to go to YTOCalculatorViewController, but although it pops to the right viewcontroller, the navigationbar shows the wrong name and after clicking the back button, it shows the right name.

For example I have on the stack 
      C
      B
      A

In this case A is YTOCalculatorViewController.
When C is being displayed, I save the information and I want to display A again, so that I use the above code.

And if I go from A to C and then back to C to A a number of times x, then when I arrive in A, I have to click x times on the back button in order to see the right uinavigationbar's name that belongs to A. The uinavigationbar displays the name of the B viewcontroller, instead of showing the name of A.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to pop from self to self..

If you want to pop to some specific controller which is already pushed.. Say you have pushed A->B->C->D, you are currently on **D** and want to popto **B**, you should do the following

```
for(UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]){
    if([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]]){
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }

}
```

The above should work well.. The code above might not be syntactically correct please correct if so.